# Are there any well known thinktecture's identity server alternatives?

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

anyone knows any other identity servers besides thinktecture's identity server? I need to evaluate a few but I can't find anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identity Server is an excellent open source offering. I'm not aware of any other OSS offerings in that space. But there are many commercial offerings (mine, among others). It might help if you expanded on the requirements you have and why Identity Server is not enough, or why you need to compare.

> BTW, Your question might be closed or flagged as it is too open ended and not specific. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). I'd encourage you to expand it with as many details as possible.

Comment: sorry, it's not that Identity Server wasn't enough, I just wanted to know if there are any other popular ones out there. It was strange that after googling, Identity Server was the only result I found.

Answer (score 16):

**AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server**

They are a lower level alternative that works with OWIN/Katana and Core.

https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

**OpenIddict**

"OpenIddict is based on ASP.NET Core Identity (for user management) and relies on **AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server** to control the OpenID Connect authentication flow."

https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core